# Put key Value of NSMutableDictionary of NSMutableArray on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am New at iPhone Development.

I have Dictionary of Array.

```
{
    A =     (
               {
                address = "Talala (gir)";
                "main_id" = 1;
                mobile = 8878876884;
                name = "Amit Patel";
               },
               {
                address = "Junagdh";
                "main_id" = 5;
                mobile = 4894679865;
                name = "Arjun Patel";
               }
            );
        J = (
                {
                address = "Taveli";
                "main_id" = 6;
                mobile = 87886356085878;
                name = "Jasmin Patel";
                },
                {
                address = "Gujarat";
                "main_id" = 4;
                mobile = 6636633368;
                name = "Jatin ";
               }
           );
        R =     (
                    {
                address = "Mumbai";
                "main_id" = 2;
                mobile = 999686322;
                name = "Rajan Patel";
            }
        );
        S =     (
                    {
                address = "Rajkot";
                "main_id" = 3;
                mobile = 8866086549;
                name = "Sumit Patel";
            }
        );
    }
```

I have `UITableView` and i want to display value which has key `"name"` on `UITableViewCell`

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.finalPDic objectForKey:[self.listOfHeader objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    return cell;
}
```

But above code is crush not work for me.

Comment: [self.listOfHeader objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:0-->depends your array count not on indexpath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    return cell;

Comment: @downVote..i am new for iOS...atleast give me reason for down vote :(

Comment: @Manohar-then how can i solve it ??

Comment: I didn't downvote to you.... i never downvote to anyone

Comment: When you post a question about a crash (not "crush"), you need to post detail about the error message and which line of code caused the crash.

Comment: @user2289379: Perhaps the *first* `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` should be `objectAtIndex:indexPath.section` ?

Comment: @rmaddy- crash at cell.textLabel.text.....and error is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Comment: @user2289379 You should update your question with that information so people will see it. As you can see from the error, you are trying to get a value beyond the range of one of the arrays. Do yourself a favor and split that one line into about 5. Assign each piece to its own variable so you can read it better and debug it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite some issues with this code ...

The first indexPath.row has to be **indexPath.section**.

As a general hint, it would be better to organize your code more readable, like:

```
NSArray* nameArrayForLetter = [self.finalPDic objectForKey:[self.listOfHeader objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSDictionary* addressDict = [nameArrayForLetter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString* nameString = [addressDict objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: thanks bro..your code is  work for me (it is very useful for newbie):)

Answer (score 0):

Your code iterates through the root keys one by one, but you wont start by index 0 in the lower levels. (the S key is the 4th, so you want the 3rd item it that array, which doesnt exists.

try using sections. A..S is the section and the rows are the names!